# Manhwa about female lead reincarnated to noble family with magic but she has no mana

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manhwa about a female lead reincarnated into a noble family with magic but she has no mana.

She was an Engineering or Architecture student so she could use mathematical equations to manage magic.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this would merit a downvote. There's a bunch of unique features here.

Answer (score 8):

This is *['Isn’t Being A Wicked Woman Much Better?'](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57002908-agnyeoraseo-pyeonhago-joh-eundeyo)*.

It was originally a light novel, but has now been adapted into a long-form webcomic.

Truck-kun kills an engineering student who is reincarnated into a villainous female, Deborah Seymour. She has no mana, but she eventually works out that magic is based on maths.

The story itself is secondary to the  lavish artwork. The artist is *obsessed* with dresses and ballgowns.

> [image]

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/56073591) is quite instructive.

> Villainess never failed for me before, i don’t think. i loooooved how scared everyone is of deborah. i mean, she did a lot of horrible things in the past but now that **a modern girl is reincarnated/transmigrated into her body, she has changed. although she don’t have mana to do magic, deborah used her modern math knowledge to improve the magical system.**

Comment: Uh, I think could get one dress or two as a gift for Christmas.