# Manhwa - Reincarnated girl sees the similarity of math and magic in her world

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

So I remember watching a manhwa recap but now the video is gone and I can’t remember much about the manhwa and I want to read it. Unfortunately the only thing that I can remember is that the girl before she was reincarnated(as a villainess I think) she did maths. So after she was reincarnated she saw similarities between the magic in the new world and maths in her old world. She found a new discovery using maths from her old world and she proved it somewhere I think and the ml was watching her and that’s all that I remember. If anyone can help me then please do(I am quite desperate)!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might it be *[Isn't Being A Wicked Woman Much Better?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57002908-agnyeoraseo-pyeonhago-joh-eundeyo)* as per [Manhwa about female lead reincarnated to noble family with magic but she has no mana](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/281478/23243)?

[image: Front cover of Isn't Being A Wicked Woman Much Better?]

> It was originally a light novel, but has now been adapted into a long-form webcomic.
>
> Truck-kun kills an engineering student who is reincarnated into a villainous female, Deborah Seymour. She has no mana, but she eventually works out that magic is based on maths.
>
> The story itself is secondary to the lavish artwork. The artist is obsessed with dresses and ballgowns.